# How to define different behavior for JUnit @Before hook with Maven and Cucumber

Tags: java, maven, cucumber, cucumber-jvm

My challenge is that I have two different types of tests that run using Cucumber BDD with Java, Maven, and JUnit.

In several features, related to the UI, I need to perform some actions before every single scenario such as spinning up VMs, like this:

```
public class StepDefinitions {
    @Before
    protected void setUp(Scenario scenario) throws MalformedURLException {
        //Create browser resources here for all of my UI related scenarios
}
```

However, in non-UI tests, such as API tests, I don't need those browsers to be spun up. Hence, I really need a different behavior for the @Before method called **setUp**.

The challenge that I am facing is that it seems as though the @Before hook works for every single test method, even if these methods are in different classes. As a result, no matter what I try, the browser resources are always created, even for API tests that don't need the browsers.

Here is what I've tried without success:

- I created a totally separate feature file and StepDefinitions file for the API tests. The definitions file has no reference to @Before method. However, the @Before from the UI tests step definitions still gets executed for the API features. Here's an example of how I separated the files( before, I had them in the exact same package even though the image is showing in different packages): https://screencast.com/t/ht5Jz4cLC

  - I tried to create new packages for the types of tests such as .api and .ui. This works when I run through IntelliJ, but doesn't work when I execute "mvn test". Seems that no tests are found or executed. Here is how this setup looks: https://screencast.com/t/uSlB4sYTFm
  - I tried to set a static property in one of my test methods that would decide if I have an API test and then update implementation in **setUp()** based on that. This of course didn't work because **setUp()** gets executed before the actual test that knows if it's a UI or API test.

Is there a way to change the behavior of setUp in an automated way so that it executes/doesn't execute the appropriate logic based on the test type (API/UI)?

Comment: I would suggest to  use [qaf](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/bdd-syntax.html) instead where driver management is taken care by framework. You can have API/UI orchestration with inbuilt [web-service automation support](https://github.com/qmetry/qaf-support-ws). If you have existing project you easily [migrate](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/gherkin_client.html#for-existing-cucumber-implementation) to qaf.

Comment: U can try using a tag for UI tests and use the same in the Before hook. Run them with a runner in which the tag option has the same value. For API tests u can use a "not @ui" as tag value for the runner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use tagged hooks to do this:
"Hooks can be conditionally selected for execution based on the tags of the scenario. To run a particular hook only for certain scenarios, you can associate a Hook with a tag expression." from the [docs](https://docs.cucumber.io/cucumber/api/#tagged-hooks).

Answer (score 2):

```
Feature File :- Hainvg 2 Scenarios, one for UI and other one for API

@UI
Scenario: This is First UI Scenario running on chrome browser
 Given this is the first step
 When this is the second step
 Then this is the third step

@Non-UI 
Scenario: This is First Non-UI Scenario running on chrome browser
 Given this is the first step
 When this is the second step
 Then this is the third step

 ------------------------------------------ Hook Implementation ------------------------------------------
@Before("@UI")
    public void beforeUISetup(){
       Do here :- In several features, related to the UI, I need to perform some actions before every single scenario such as spinning up VMs
    } 

@Before("@Non-UI")
    public void beforeNon-UIScenario(){
     Do here :- in non-UI tests, such as API tests, I don't need those browsers to be spun up
    }
```

In case, you need to run Non-UI @Before method first then we can set order of these @Before as well.